# Redis CPU usage and tuning

Tags: performance, hash, redis

I have designed a structure to store customer information in Redis following this clear but old article:http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value

The parameter I'm using is to tune the hash's max entries is the new 'hash-max-ziplist-entries' instead the old 'hash-zipmap-max-entries' that the article says, and set it to 1000.

The parameter hash-max-ziplist-values is not clear to me, but I changed it to 1024

It turns out that Redis consumes 100% CPU, so, as it's a shared server, the rest of the processes hungs.

What can I do?

We are using Redis 3.0.1 in AIX 6.1.